# How do i fix bug with @media in css?

Tags: css, wordpress-theming

I`m creating theme for wordpress. Write this code for test

```
@media all and (min-width: 900px){
body{
    border:5px red dotted;
}}
```

But browser show it, if as i write

```
@media all and (min-width: 1350px){
body{
    border:5px red dotted;
}}
```

Wats a ploblem might be?

Comment: If this is the complete code, you just missed one closing } at the end - body is closed, but media is open. And, of course, the whole css has to be wrapped in a style - tag, in case it's not already in a css file.

Comment: no no, i have mistake, actually } is in my code.

Comment: The question is not clear, what exactly is the problem?

Comment: PS: try pressing CTRL+0 and test the page again.

Comment: i write min-width: 900px, but when I open page in browser, it behaves like min-width: 1350px

Comment: Just to be sure - you already added a viewport - metatag in the head-section?

Answer (score 0):

Double check that you're editing the correct file. If you're 100% that you are, it's probably a caching issue. Try pressing **Ctrl+Shift+R** or **Cmd+Shift+R** to force a reload of the file.

Comment: i try open this page in other browser, and trying press Ctrl+Shift+R . So, nothing change =(

Comment: This should be a comment. And it that solves the problem the question should be closed and deleted instead.

Comment: Do you have a live link to the website that I can look at?